# Excel - Fill rows with certain step

Tags: excel, rows, fill

I am really finding this weirdly hard to explain but I want to perform a rows automatic fill operation in excel and I am having this problem.
I have these rows:

```
1 = A1
2 = D1
3 = G1
4 = J1
5 = M1
6 = O1
```

I want to repeat this sequence so that 7 = A2, 8 = D2 etc. Auto fill completes 7 as A7, 8 as D7, a 6 cell step insted of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should 6 be P1 so that there is a gap of 2 between each column? Or is 6 different?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I mistyped O1

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using offset: =OFFSET(Sheet1!AA$2;P6;0) where P:P is a column filled with numbers like this: 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3 etc.

Comment: Nice data-driven approach.

Comment: I didn't get this - wouldn't you need another column filled with 0,9,18,27,36,45,0,9,18... to get AA2,AJ2 etc?

Answer (score 0):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1+6)
```

and copy both down and across:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I probably did not make myself clear, so I am going to rephrase the question as this: Let's say that instead of A1, D1 etc. I have AA1 (a cell not in the column I want to apply this, maybe in another sheet). So, AA1, then AJ1, AS1, cells that have a certain distance between each other. This happens for a group of 6 cells and then I want the count to start again from AA2, AJ2, AS2 etc. The problem is that when I autofill the group of 6 cells it jumps to AA7 (having 6 as a step) and not to AA2. Thanks again!

Comment: @GiannisTsouros  I am sorry...........now I am sure I do not understand.

Comment: I think I've got it, OP wants to go down a column with references to A1, then D1 and G1 etc. so each time he goes down one row the references will skip two columns and go to the next column (until he has done 6, then it will go to the next row).

Comment: @TomSharpe  I will update the formula later..........this is a little more complex

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you are filling your column with references =A1, =D1, =G1 etc. you don't get the behaviour you're after. One way round it (not really recommended) is to use *text* values A1, D1, G1 etc. If you highlight these, pull down and fill series it will give you what you want. Then you can indirect them, e.g. if they are in column Q:-

```
=INDIRECT(Q1)
```

An index formula is better:-

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$100,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)/6+1,MOD((ROWS($A$1:A1)-1),6)*3+1)
```